# MQ Cluster - how to properly disable one node in production environments

Tags: ibm-mq

I have some messages flowing through the MQ cluster by using cluster and alias queues. Some queues are defined multiple times, though the loadbalancing mechanism is used.

What is the propper way to extract one QM from the cluster without disturbing the whole message flow? Disabling the cluster-receiver channel, cluster-sender channels, or else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the

> suspend qmgr

command.

This suspends the queue manager from the cluster.

[command reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.csqzaj.doc/sc13490_.htm)